# compiler over-optimization causing data run time and debugging inconsistency

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
struct cre_eqEntry *      
cre_eventGet(struct cre_eqObj *eq_obj)
{
   struct cre_eqEntry *eqe = cre_queueTailNode(&eq_obj->q);
   Memcpy(&tmpEqo, eq_obj, sizeof(struct cre_eqObj)); 
   volatile u32 ddd = 0;
   ddd = ((struct cre_eqEntry *)(eq_obj->q.dma_mem.virtaddr + 4 * eq_obj->q.tail))->evt;
   CPUMemFenceReadWrite();    

   if (!ddd) {
      tmp = eq_obj->q.tail;                                                                                                                                                                                 
      assert(0);
      return NULL;
   }   
}
```

It is a piece of kernel code. When I ran it, it fails at assert(0). So apparently ddd should be 0. But when I used GDB to debug the core dump and printed out '((struct cre_eqEntry *)(eq_obj->q.dma_mem.virtaddr + 4 * eq_obj->q.tail))->evt', surprisingly, the value is not 0.

So I start suspecting it is the problem of compiler over-optimization. Here's the disassembly code:

```
00000000000047ec <cre_eventGet>:
    47ec:       55                      push   %rbp
    47ed:       48 89 fe                mov    %rdi,%rsi
    47f0:       ba 80 00 00 00          mov    $0x80,%edx
    47f5:       53                      push   %rbx
    47f6:       48 89 fb                mov    %rdi,%rbx
    47f9:       48 83 ec 18             sub    $0x18,%rsp
    47fd:       0f b7 6f 24             movzwl 0x24(%rdi),%ebp
    4801:       0f b7 47 28             movzwl 0x28(%rdi),%eax
    4805:       0f af e8                imul   %eax,%ebp
    4808:       48 63 ed                movslq %ebp,%rbp
    480b:       48 03 6f 18             add    0x18(%rdi),%rbp
    480f:       48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi        # 4816 <cre_eventGet+0x2a>
    4816:       e8 00 00 00 00          callq  481b <cre_eventGet+0x2f>
    481b:       0f b7 43 28             movzwl 0x28(%rbx),%eax
    481f:       48 8b 53 18             mov    0x18(%rbx),%rdx
    4823:       c7 44 24 0c 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0xc(%rsp)
    482a:       00 
    482b:       c1 e0 02                shl    $0x2,%eax
    482e:       48 98                   cltq   
    4830:       8b 04 02                mov    (%rdx,%rax,1),%eax
    4833:       89 44 24 0c             mov    %eax,0xc(%rsp)
    4837:       0f ae f0                mfence 
    483a:       8b 44 24 0c             mov    0xc(%rsp),%eax
    483e:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
    4840:       74 14                   je     4856 <cre_eventGet+0x6a>
```

As far as I can see, the assembly code does the same thing as the C code.

So now I ran out of ideas what is causing the problem of inconsistency of 'ddd'.

Please kindly give me some hints!

Comment: This `assert` call always generates an error message (of course only if NDEBUG isn't defined). It is executed if `!ddd`. Doesn't that mean `ddd` **should** be non-zero? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Is another core or a device modifying `ptr->evt`?

Comment: Have you tried to run it in gdb with a break point on `cre_eventGet` to see what happen step by step?

Comment: I assume that you have all optimization turned off at build time?

Comment: What prevents multiple events from overlapping and clobbering tmpEqo?

Comment: In GDB, I printed out 'ddd', it's "0". I can't run it in gdb with a break point, it's a kernel dump. I believe I have some optimizations turned on. This piece of code stays in ISR. tmpEqo should not be important in this case since we don't use it.

Comment: Is this your [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? If so, it doesn't seem complete; please read the page that I just linked to. Make sure your code is **minimal** (which isn't a problem at the moment; your code is so minimal that it doesn't yet compile), **compilable** (this is currently a problem for your question) and **verifiable** (we can't verify anything because we can't compile). Once you provide such an example, I think you'll find the problem is almost certainly not *over-optimisation*; you're most likely misdiagnosing and diverting our eyes from the real problem.

Comment: I believe `volatile` has no effect here. If the memory fence actually fences then it is redundant; and if the fence doesn't fence then it doesn't actually help.

Answer (score 0):

`ddd = ((struct cre_eqEntry *)(eq_obj->q.dma_mem.virtaddr + 4 * eq_obj->q.tail))->evt;`

Simplify your code. Perform address/boundary checks/validation. Your problem is likely that you are de-referencing some random, uninitialized, address within your process/thread's address space.

Answer (score 0):

`ddd = ((struct cre_eqEntry *)(eq_obj->q.dma_mem.virtaddr + 4 * eq_obj->q.tail))->evt;` probably violates the strict aliasing rule  (can't say 100% for sure without seeing the whole code).

If using gcc/clang, compile with `-fno-strict-aliasing` unless you want to rewrite your code to comply with the standard.

To do the latter, `memcpy((u32 *)&ddd, &(struct cre_eqEntry *)(eq_obj->q.dma_mem.virtaddr + 4 * eq_obj->q.tail)->evt, sizeof ddd);`  but I guess your codebase may have similar violations in many places, so as a first step, using the compiler flag would be a way to see if this really is the problem.

The magic number `4` is suspicious too, review your code to check if this really is the correct offset and also check that it is not out of bounds of allocated memory.